# tfjs-models universal sentence encoder's embed() breaking ONLY ON PHYSICAL DEVICE

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to generate word embeddings from a list of strings using [tfjs-models Universal Sentence Encoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder) within the React Native framework. THIS CODE WORKS on an emulated iOS device but throws an error on a physical iPhone:

```
encoder = await use.load();
console.log("Encoding material keys from JSON file...")
try {
  const validInput = ["howdy", "hello"]
  const embeddings =  await encoder.embed(validInput);
  tf.print(embeddings);
  embeddingsArray = embeddings.arraySync();
}
catch(err) {
  console.log("Problem encoding material keys");
  throw err;
}
```

Here are the logs including the error:

```
Encoding material keys from JSON file...
Problem encoding material keys
Problem initializing encoder or embeddings
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.substr')]
```

After looking at the source code for the embed() function, it seems it's saying the input to the embed() function is undefined. As you can see, I've ensured I passed it valid input. It accepts either a string or array of strings as input.

Is this an issue with tfjs-react-native not fully supporting tfjs-models? [This project](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-48a39185717c) led me to believe this type of functionality is supported.

Comment: `tfjs-react-native` does fully support `tfjs-models`. Could you try making the sentences longer and adding more sentences? Could you try updating the version of `tfjs-react-native` that you are using?

Comment: This error occurred using tfjs-react-native version 0.5.0 (current). The same error occurs with a list of two strings and a list of 344 strings.